# when I use the c++ STL sort function in string sort,there is some problem

Tags: c++, sorting

**C++ code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int
main ()
{
  vector < string > elem (4);
  ifstream infile ("test.txt");
  if (!infile)
    {
      cerr << "Oops! unable to save session data !\n";
    }
  int i;
  for (i = 0; infile >> elem[i]; i++);
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      cout << elem[i] << ' ';
    }
  cout << "\nThe result after sorting\n";
  sort (elem, elem + 4);
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      cout << elem[i] << ' ';
    }
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

THis is my full code,when I run,there is some problem

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: 
main.cpp:24:20: error: no match
for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::vector >’ and ‘int’)    sort
(elem, elem + x);
       ~~~~~^~~
```

[image]

Comment: elem is a `std::vector`, not a `std::string *`. You should use `std::vector.begin()` and `std::vector.end()`

Comment: Try replacing `sort(elem, elem + 4);` with `sort(std::begin(elem), std::end(elem));`. What reference are you working from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your usage of `std::sort` is C-ish. You have to supply iterators to begin/end, i.e., write something like

```
sort(elem.begin(), elem.end());
```

Besides, your program will crash if the `test.txt` file is more than 4 lines (trying to read into non-existent `elem[4]`).

Be careful though, check that the default comparison does what you want. Here it does.